# How can I overload the new operator for multiple heaps?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

In an embedded system with two separate RAM memory areas, I have two distinct heaps (one is a custom implementation from FreeRTOS in the lower memory area, another is the heap generated by GCC in the upper memory area) and I would like to be able to choose which heap new uses.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could provide an `operator new` overload that accepts a second argument telling it which memory area to allocate memory from.  You can give arguments to `operator new` by putting them in parenthesis before the type in your new-expression.  This is usually used to `new` an object into already-allocated storage (since that's the overload provided by the standard library), but anything can be passed there and it will be passed on to `operator new`.

```
enum MemoryArea {
    LOWER,
    UPPER
};

void* operator new(std::size_t sz, MemoryArea seg) {
    if (seg == LOWER) {
        return allocateMemoryInLowerMemoryArea(sz);
    } else {
        return allocateMemoryInUpperMemoryArea(sz);
    }
}

void operator delete(void* p) {
    if (pointerIsInLowerMemoryArea(p)) {
        freeMemoryFromLowerMemoryArea(p);
    } else {
        freeMemoryFromUpperMemoryArea(p);
    }
}

int main() {
    Foo* p = new (LOWER) Foo;
    Foo* b = new (UPPER) Foo;
    delete p;
    delete b;
}
```

Comment: That's not placement new. Placement new instantiates an object in-place and does not allocate memory.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious It's the same syntax as placement new, and uses the same mechanisms, but I suppose you're right.  I'll re-word that bit.

Comment: _"It's the same syntax "_ but not the same semantics which is more important.

Comment: It looks like the standard does actually refer to this as a _placement new-expression_, regardless of what the `operator new` overload actually does with the parameters.  See §[expr.new]/13.

Comment: Placement new takes size_t and void*. This does not.

Comment: The standard defines _placement new-expression_ to be any _new-expression_ for which a _new-placement_ clause is provided.  The _new-placment_ clause is the parenthesized expression list before the type name in the _new-expression_.  It's probably still true that this shouldn't be colloquially referred to as placement new, but it is technically correct.

Answer (score -4):

**Edit: See accepted answer, this is incorrect - UseUpperMemoryNew would affect allocations of MyClass, not allocations within functions in MyClass.** Leaving this around for learning / posterity / comments.

For the lower memory area, in global namespace

```
#include <new>
#undef new

void* operator new (std::size_t size) throw (std::bad_alloc) { ... }
void* operator new (std::size_t size, const std::nothrow_t& nothrow_constant) { ... }
void* operator new[] (std::size_t size) throw (std::bad_alloc) { ... }
void* operator new[] (std::size_t size, const std::nothrow_t& nothrow_constant) throw() { ... }
void operator delete (void* ptr) throw () { ... }
void operator delete (void* ptr, const std::nothrow_t& nothrow_constant) throw() { ... }
void operator delete[] (void* ptr) throw () { ... }
void operator delete[] (void* ptr, const std::nothrow_t& nothrow_constant) throw() { ... }
```

For the upper memory area,

```
void* new2 (std::size_t size) throw (std::bad_alloc) { ... }
void* new2 (std::size_t size, const std::nothrow_t& nothrow_constant) { ... }
void delete2 (void* ptr) throw () { ... }
void delete2 (void* ptr, const std::nothrow_t& nothrow_constant) throw() { ... }

#define UseUpperMemoryNew \
void* operator new (std::size_t size) throw (std::bad_alloc) { return new2(size); }\
void* operator new (std::size_t size, const std::nothrow_t& nothrow_constant) { return new2(size, nothrow_constant); }\
void* operator new[] (std::size_t size) throw (std::bad_alloc) { return new2(size); }\
void* operator new[] (std::size_t size, const std::nothrow_t& nothrow_constant) throw() { return new2(size, nothrow_constant); }\
void operator delete (void* ptr) throw () { delete2(ptr); }\
void operator delete (void* ptr, const std::nothrow_t& nothrow_constant) throw() { delete2(ptr, nothrow_constant); }\
void operator delete[] (void* ptr) throw () { delete2(ptr); }\
void operator delete[] (void* ptr, const std::nothrow_t& nothrow_constant) throw() { delete2(ptr, nothrow_constant); }
```

Then, lower memory is default, upper memory may be chosen at the class level:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    UseUpperMemoryArea
    void someFunction(); // new operator use in this function uses upper memory area
};
```

I discovered that you may not redefine new outside of the global namespace - class-level overloading is the only option here.

Comment: FYI, the `throw(...)` exception specification is [deprecated](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/except_spec).

Comment: That's not how class-specific `operator new` overloads work.  Your `UseUpperMemoryNew` overloads won't be used in `MyClass`, they will be used to allocate new `MyClass` objects.

Comment: If you're gonna do a self-answered post you're gonna need to do a bit better than this.

Comment: Posting an incorrect, unaccepted answer to my own question revealed it's flaws, improved my code, and taught me a few new things. I'd call that doing pretty well.

Comment: It might be an idea to move this to an "appendix" in the question body.